# HTML: click the button, it changes color. Then click the button, however, it doesn't change to original color

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to achieve a functionality where I click the correct answer, it turns into green. If click the wrong answer, it turns into red. Next I want to add a functionality: if I click the right-answer button twice, it first changes into specific color with first click, and changes into white with second click. However, this additional functionality comes with a bug. It can't turn into original color.
I try to use `hello` to achieve this additional functionality, but somewhere seems to be wrong...

```js
let b = document.querySelectorAll('.false');
let hello = -1;
document.querySelector('.true').addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (hello === 0) {
    document.querySelector('.true').style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    document.getElementById('check').innerHTML = null;
  }
  hello = 0;
  document.querySelector('.true').style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  document.querySelector('#check').innerHTML = 'Correct!';
  document.querySelector('#check').style.color = 'green';
  for (let i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    b[i].style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  }
})

for (let i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
  b[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (hello === 1) {
      b[i].style.backgroundColor = 'white';
      document.getElementById('check').innerHTML = null;
    }
    hello = 1;
    b[i].style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    document.querySelector('#check').innerHTML = 'Incorrect.';
    document.querySelector('#check').style.color = 'red';
    b[b.length - i - 1].style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    document.querySelector('.true').style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  })
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Trivia!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h3>IP version</h3>
  <button class="false" style="background-color: white">IPv3</button>
  <button class="true" style="background-color: white">IPv4</button>
  <button class="false" style="background-color: white">IPv5</button>
  <p id="check"></p>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though your if statement runs, you overwrite styles after that. You got 2 cases:

1. Where it is first time clicking the correct button,
2. It is second time clicking the correct button

So a simple if - else will solve this:
(I also made changes on some styling, because in your code correct button were red, and wrong buttons were green.)

```js
  let b = document.querySelectorAll('.false');
  let hello = -1;
  document.querySelector('.true').addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (hello === 0) {
      hello = -1;
      document.querySelector('.true').style.backgroundColor = 'white';
      document.getElementById('check').innerHTML = null;
    } else {
      hello = 0;
      document.querySelector('.true').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
      document.querySelector('#check').innerHTML = 'Correct!';
      document.querySelector('#check').style.color = 'green';
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
      b[i].style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    }
  })

  for (let i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    b[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
      if (hello === 1) {
        b[i].style.backgroundColor = 'white';
        document.getElementById('check').innerHTML = null;
      }
      hello = 1;
      b[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
      document.querySelector('#check').innerHTML = 'Incorrect.';
      document.querySelector('#check').style.color = 'red';
      b[b.length - i - 1].style.backgroundColor = 'white';
      document.querySelector('.true').style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    })
  }
```

```html
  <h3>IP version</h3>
  <button class="false" style="background-color: white">IPv3</button>
  <button class="true" style="background-color: white">IPv4</button>
  <button class="false" style="background-color: white">IPv5</button>
  <p id="check"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you! If I don't add else statement, after background changes into white, it will quickly change into green

Comment: Happy to help. You can mark my answer as solution if it is as you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a `return` keyword inside the conditional checking `hello === 0`, as shown below:

```
let b = document.querySelectorAll('.false');
let hello = -1;
document.querySelector('.true').addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (hello === 0) {
    document.querySelector('.true').style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    document.getElementById('check').innerHTML = null;
    return; // THIS IS ADDED
  }
  hello = 0;
  document.querySelector('.true').style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  document.querySelector('#check').innerHTML = 'Correct!';
  document.querySelector('#check').style.color = 'green';
  for (let i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    b[i].style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  }
})

// .......
```

BTW, you must swap the `'red'` and `'green'` strings in your code where you style the `background-color` CSS property, because right now when we click the wrong button, it is made green (where it should have been made red).

So the correct code will be:

```
let b = document.querySelectorAll('.false');
let hello = -1;
document.querySelector('.true').addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (hello === 0) {
    document.querySelector('.true').style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    document.getElementById('check').innerHTML = null;
    return
  }
  hello = 0;
  document.querySelector('.true').style.backgroundColor = 'green'; // CHANGED HERE
  document.querySelector('#check').innerHTML = 'Correct!';
  document.querySelector('#check').style.color = 'green';
  for (let i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    b[i].style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  }
})

for (let i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
  b[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (hello === 1) {
      b[i].style.backgroundColor = 'white';
      document.getElementById('check').innerHTML = null;
    }
    hello = 1;
    b[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red'; // CHANGED HERE
    document.querySelector('#check').innerHTML = 'Incorrect.';
    document.querySelector('#check').style.color = 'red';
    b[b.length - i - 1].style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    document.querySelector('.true').style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  })
}
```

Comment: Oh, return statement should be added! By the way, hello=-1 should also be added before return statement

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve in this way too.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".false").forEach((value) => {
  value.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let currentColor = document.getElementById(value.id);
    currentColor.style.backgroundColor =
      currentColor.style.backgroundColor === "red" ? "white" : "red";
  });
});

document.querySelectorAll(".true").forEach((value) => {
  value.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let currentColor = document.getElementById(value.id);
    currentColor.style.backgroundColor =
      currentColor.style.backgroundColor === "green" ? "white" : "green";
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Trivia!</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h3>IP version</h3>
    <button id="1" class="false" style="background-color: white;">IPv3</button>
    <button id="2" class="true" style="background-color: white;">IPv4</button>
    <button id="3" class="false" style="background-color: white;">IPv5</button>
    <p id="check"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When submitting a code, mention the changes or any additions you have done to the questioner's code and explain why you did them. Just a working code doesn't do the job